# zsh inserts extra spaces when performing searches and completion

Tags: shell, command-prompt, zsh, prompt, ansi-escape

I have written a small program that emits a command line prompt with some Git info. I use ANSI escape sequences to color it, and it looks something like this:

[image: prompt example]

However, whenever I do tab completion or a search, zsh inserts several spaces after the prompt:

[image: spacing bug]

It seems to be inserting a space for each escape code character emitted by the prompt, since removing the color codes eliminates this behavior. Why is zsh doing so, and how can I stop this?

The actual character sequence emitted by my prompt program for this example is (assuming `\e` represents character 033)

```
~/s/promptd [\e[36mmaster \e[33m±\e[31m?\e[39m]
```

The relevant portion of my `.zshrc` is:

```
setopt PROMPT_SUBST
setopt PROMPT_PERCENT
PROMPT='%B$(promptd) %%%b '
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After doing some additional research, the [ZSH Prompt Expansion docs](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html) indicate that escape literals need to be enclosed in `%{...%}`.

This is bothersome since now I have to output those conditionally if I want the prompt program to work in other shells, but it seems to correct the behavior shown above.

Comment: If unclear where to use this, see the following answear which makes it more clear when %{ %} needs to be used:  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85058/zsh-adds-tab-character-when-autocompleting